# Grouping in Postgres by a custom column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a bit of complex requirement for a Postgres query. I want to group by a custom expression:

```
SELECT column_1, column_2, column_3 aggregate_function(column_4)
FROM tbl_name
GROUP BY custom_field
```

In the custom field I want `column_1+column_2` if `column_3` is blank else `column_3`. This is because some data has `column_3` split into `column_1` and `column_2`. The fields `column_1`, `column_2` and `column_3` are `VARCHAR.`

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not select a single column in a query have group by if it not either in aggregate function or group by phase. I mean that you can not select `column_1`, `column_2` and `column_3` separately. For your require, I suggest the query like this.

```
SELECT COALESCE(NULLIF(column_3,''), concat(column_1,column_2)) as custom_field, 
        aggregate_function(column_4)
FROM tbl_name
GROUP BY custom_field
```

OR

```
SELECT CASE
           WHEN NULLIF(column_3,'') IS NULL THEN concat(column_1,column_2)
           ELSE column_3
        END as custom_field, 
        aggregate_function(column_4)
FROM tbl_name
GROUP BY custom_field
```

Hopefully my answer will satisfy you.

Comment: In the select part, can I add the columns as well after the custom_field?

Comment: If you put any column in `select` phase, unless it is in `aggregate function`, you must put into `Group By` phase too.

Comment: I am getting 'column "column_2" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function' even when it is not selected separately

Comment: Ignore the last comment. It works when I use custom_field as name

Answer (score 0):

New version with JSON

```
SELECT -- how to use json
   m.columns->>'column_1'
   , m.columns->>'column_2'
   , m.columns->>'column_3'
   , m.aggregate_function
FROM
(
   -- example of query
   SELECT CASE column_3 WHEN '' 
              THEN jsonb_build_object('column_1', column_1, 'column_2', column_2) 
              ELSE jsonb_build_object('column_3', column_3) 
          END AS columns
          , aggregate_function(column_4) AS aggregate_function 
   FROM tbl_name
   GROUP BY 1

) AS m
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT max(column_1) AS column_1
    , max(column_2) AS column_2
    , max(column_3) AS column_3
    , aggregate_function(column_4)
FROM tbl_name
GROUP BY CASE  
            WHEN column_3='' THEN (column_1, column_2, ''::varchar) 
            ELSE (''::varchar,''::varchar,column_3) 
          END
```

Comment: When you run this query, you force to use the `max` value of column instead of the data they want.

Comment: What data do they want? How to use column 1 and column 2 separately, after concat (column_1, column_2)?

Comment: yes, but if we run the query as you suggest? you force us get the `max value` of 3 columns instead of it was. If you wanna use column_1 and column_2 after query you can concat and then split it by a special character. such as `@@@@@`

Comment: O-o-o, NO! We are archaic ... both. The modern is JSON!